# Merge two JSON class with children

Tags: c#, angularjs, json

I have a JSON class as follows :

```
    [
{
    "url": "", 
    "expanded": false, 
    "label": "Reports", 
    "last_modified": "2014-09-28T11:19:49.000Z", 
    "type": 2, 
    "children": [
        {
            "url": "", 
            "expanded": false, 
            "label": "2014", 
            "last_modified": "2014-09-28T11:19:49.000Z",
          "type": 2
            }}]
```

How i create only a JSON class with datatable as follows?
I want use this child in treegrid in AngularJs.thnx

```
 "children": [
                    {
                        "url": "foo.pdf", 
                        "expanded": false, 
                        "label": "E14288-Passive-40085-2014_09_26.pdf", 
                        "last_modified": "2014-09-28T11:19:49.000Z", 
                        "type": 1, 
                        "size": 60929
                    }
                ]
```

Comment: Please elaborate more. Where do you want to create it? Is it a class in model or dynamic view data or ...?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Do you have the `children` list and want to know how to serialize it? And what do you mean by merging?

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still not clear. Do you want to extract the `children` property of the original class? Or do you want to create a `children` list with two elements? Do you have any deserialization code? We cannot help you if we don't understand what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: So you want to deserialize this children json to Datable right ?

Comment: Why rank my question is reduce????

Answer (score 1):

> How I create only a JSON class with datatable as follows?

So first you need to `Deserialize` your json to Object. After that you need to map this object to `DataTable` using reflection.

I strongly advise you to google search this 3 bullets, if you don't understand something from the answer:

- How to Deserialize json to Object
- What is reflection , how to use reflection
- How to create DataTable from scratch.

Full example: [**dotNetFiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oS0pbz)

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @" {
        ""children"": [
                {
            ""url"": ""foo.pdf"", 
                    ""expanded"": false, 
                    ""label"": ""E14288-Passive-40085-2014_09_26.pdf"", 
                    ""last_modified"": ""2014-09-28T11:19:49.000Z"", 
                    ""type"": 1, 
                    ""size"": 60929
                }
            ]
         }";

        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChildrenRootObject>(json);
        DataTable tbl = DataTableFromObject(result.children);
    }

    public static DataTable DataTableFromObject<T>(IList<T> list)
    {
        DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
        tbl.TableName = typeof(T).Name;

        var propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        List<string> columnNames = new List<string>();

        foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
        {
            tbl.Columns.Add(propertyInfo.Name, propertyInfo.PropertyType);
            columnNames.Add(propertyInfo.Name);
        }

        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            DataRow row = tbl.NewRow();
            foreach (var name in columnNames)
            {
                row[name] = item.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(item, null);
            }

            tbl.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        return tbl;
    }

    public class Child
    {
        public string url { get; set; }
        public bool expanded { get; set; }
        public string label { get; set; }
        public DateTime last_modified { get; set; }
        public int type { get; set; }
        public int size { get; set; }
    }

    public class ChildrenRootObject
    {
        public List<Child> children { get; set; }
    }
```